# Q value for a high pass filter

Tags: filters, audio, sound

How to calculate the Q value for a high pass filter ?
Ps: I'm a beginner in signal processing, so please put it in simple terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [these set of notes](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/43-09/edch%208%20filter.pdf) provided by Analog Devices as part of their "Basic Linear Design" seminar, or just look for notes on second order filters.

The transfer function of a second order high pass filter is 
$$H(s) = \frac{A s^2}{s^2+\frac{w_0}{Q}s+w_0^2}$$ where $w_0$ is the cutoff frequency, $Q$ is the $Q$-factor, and $A$ is the gain.